# Angular: in ngOnInit() My rxjs Fucntion dont run when I reload my component

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngoninit

My Angular application has the following components.

1 MessengerService. This service I am using to send/get data to other components using RxJs.
The code of the service is here.

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ReplaySubject, Subject} from 'rxjs';

```
 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class MessengerService {
   _Subject = new ReplaySubject(1);
   constructor() { }

   SendMessageWithData(MessageAndData){
     this._Subject.next(MessageAndData);
   }
   GetMessageWithData(){
     return this._Subject.asObservable();
   }

 }
```

2 ProductComponent. It has a button with a function and its snippet is here.

```
 SendProductId(_ProductId){
     this._MessengerService.SendMessageWithData({ //Sending data to the Messenger Service
       id:_ProductId,
       Component:'ProductComponent'
     });
     this._Router.navigate(['viewProduct']); //Then routing to the viewProduct Component
   }
```

3 My Last Component viewProduct Component Here I am getting the data from ProductCompoent using my MessengerService in ngOnInit(): void {} the snippet is following.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
     this._MessengerService.GetMessageWithData().subscribe();
                 // some code here
 }
```

Now coming to my question. When I route to viewProduct from ProductComponent function. it send the data and then in ngOnInit() the GetMessageWithData() work perfectly. But when I reload the viewComponent the function this._MessengerService.GetMessageWithData().subscribe(); in ngOnInit() do not run and the code inside it do not run. Please guide me how to fix this problem.

Comment: can you create a sandbox ?

Comment: i dont know about sandbox brother

Comment: Brother any snippet or solution for this problem?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/ recreate the problem here

Comment: How do you “reload productView component”? Are you refreshing the page?

Comment: brother my problem is simple. When i reload the viewProduct component the function which is GetMessageWithData() from Rxjs inside ngOnInit() does not run.

Comment: @BizzyBob By click on the refresh button on google chrome. (I am purposely reloading it)

Comment: So, you are restarting the app. Therefore, your message is not sent after you reload app, this is why your code isn’t executing because no message is received.

Comment: @BizzyBob so bro how to fix this thing. Do i need to return something else in GetMessageWithData().

Comment: @BizzyBob brother if you have 5 minutes can you see my problem on zoom call. Please

Comment: I think it might be easiest to get product id from route param instead of trying to send it through the message service. Other option would be to have the message service persist the latest message in localStorage so that it can re-emit it when the app first loads.

Comment: @BizzyBob bro i think i can fix it now thanks for the localstorage idea. but bro is it fine to use rxjs to send id or i should use route params? which is the professional way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230574/discussion-between-abdul-rehman-and-bizzybob).

Comment: I think the route param is generally a better approach because it allows you to have links to specific products using a simple url, and it doesn’t require you to persist that state. But if this direct linking via url isn’t desired in your case, local storage should work fine.

Comment: @BizzyBob Got it bro

BizzyBob brother any contact medium like linkedin discord or slack? so i can ask your some good advises

Comment: @BizzyBob Actually I am making an eCommerce application and I am persisting the cart using local storages. I want to ask one more thing is it a professional way to persist cart using local storage or do I need to persist it through DB

Comment: There are pros and cons to both.  DB would give the ability to access same cart from multiple devices (*like amazon does*), but it's a little more back end work to make that happen (*also assumes user is logged in*).  I think using localStorage is fine to start off with, but others may have different opinions :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reload, all the app state will be lost. Either you have to come again from productComponent or you need to pass the id of the product as route parameter to viewProduct component and query the data from the Database. This is the standard way of processing.